# How to click some button with same class

Tags: javascript

I try to make javascript to submit the button but I don't know how to select only one button I want. There're many buttons and here the button I want to submit.

```
<a href="#" class="btnVote" data-master-id="290" data-sub-id="8" data-vote-idx="14238" onclick="return false;">VOTE</a>
```

Comment: What button? The markup you posted is a link, an anchor. You cannot "select" a link, nor can you "submit" it. You may click it. What happens after the click is another question.

Comment: Same class as what? Also, where is your javascript? What have you tried so far and what specific difficulties are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Give the html element an id attribute and select the element by id.
html:

```
<a href="foo" id="bar">FooBar </a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#bar")
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("bar")
```

Answer (score -1):

Click by unique property value:

```
$('a[data-vote-idx="14238"]').click();
```